# My autocomplete ignores my JSON data and shows random numbers

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, materialize

I'm trying to add the autocomplete feature to one of my input-field, as soon as the user types the function triggers and it queries the DB to get the numbers.

This is the input field code

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m3 offset-m1 l2 offset-l1">
<input id="NumEmpleado" name="NumEmpleado" type="text" class="validate autocomplete" autocomplete="off" required="">
<label for="NumEmpleado">N° de Empleado</label>
</div>
```

This is the script code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('input', 'input.autocomplete', function() {
            let inputText = $(this).val(); //Gets text from input
            $.get('suggest.php?key=' + inputText) //Makes the query
                .done(function(suggestions) {  //gets JSON data as suggestions 
                console.log(suggestions); //Prints
                    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({ //Initialize auto complete with new data
                        data: suggestions
                    });
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is suggest.php - which is triggered when the user types

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$NumEmpleado = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'unacar');

$query= "select NumEmpleado from academico where NumEmpleado LIKE '%{$key}%'"; 
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($res->num_rows>0){
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
$NumEmpleado[trim($row["NumEmpleado"])] = null;
}
}
echo json_encode($NumEmpleado);
flush();
?>
```

I have noticed this things so far:

When I press space bar on the input field while looking at console, the json data is exactly as the data on the DB
[image: Red box is DB query in Heidi SQL]

When I press 1, which should give me the '31' as the only autocomplete option, it shows 2 options and this are not from the JSON data  and for some reason, it tries to show a image(src: uknown).

[image]

Also tries to load some stuff

[image]

If I type 9, it should give me 3 options; 9, 93, and 98

[image]
And again, it tries to reach somewhere.

Thank you for reading, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery autocomplete accept fix key and value (label and value) during initialization. So, first of all, you have to convert your result to the specific key value like below.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'suggest.php?key=' + $('#text_box_id').val(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item[0],
                                val: item[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

It might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your code is giving me an error syntax  https://i.imgur.com/tcj4C3d.png

Comment: Please check it again. The answer has been updated.